# How to evaluate Recyclerview in MVVM architecture

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-room, android-mvvm, android-database

I am creating a Notes taking app. Where on the main screen I have a floating action button . When the user will click on that button a screen will open to take the title and description of the note. Then the note will add on the screen on a recycler view on the main screen. Then if the recycler item is clicked again a dialog box will open to update the notes, and I have also a delete button to delete the notes. I have created the Entity table, Dao class , the database , repository and viewmodel. Also add the Recycler view and it's adapter. But I am struggling on the point where I am taking the title and the description from user and then how to set it on the view in the recycler view and how I can use the same layout for update also and where to implement the delete and update functionality

Here is the adapter code for recycler view

```
class NotesRecycle() : RecyclerView.Adapter<NotesRecycle.NotesViewHolder>() {
    val allNotes=ArrayList<NoteTable>()
    inner class NotesViewHolder(itemView:View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): NotesViewHolder {
        val viewholder=NotesViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.notes_item,parent,false))
        return viewholder
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NotesViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentNotes=allNotes[position]
        holder.itemView.tvtitle.text=currentNotes.title
        holder.itemView.tvdescription.text=currentNotes.description


    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
       return allNotes.size
    }
}
```

here is my MainActivity code

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var viewModel: NotesViewModel
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        recyclerview.layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(this)
        val adapter=NotesRecycle()
        recyclerview.adapter=adapter
        val dao=NotesDataBase.getDataBase(applicationContext).getNoteDao()
        val repository=NotesRepository(dao)
        viewModel=ViewModelProvider(this,NoteViewModeFactory(repository)).get(NotesViewModel::class.java)
        btnadd.setOnClickListener{
            val diolog=Dialog(this)
            diolog.setContentView(R.layout.add_update_lay_item)
            diolog.btnADD.setOnClickListener {
                val title=diolog.etTitle.text.toString()
                val description=diolog.etDescription.text.toString()
                viewModel.insertNote(NoteTable(0,title,description))
                diolog.dismiss()
            }
            diolog.show()
        }
    }
}
```

The repository class

```
class NotesRepository (private val noteDao: NoteDao) {
    val allNotes:LiveData<List<NoteTable>> = noteDao.getAllNotes()
    suspend fun insert(noteTable: NoteTable){
        noteDao.insert(noteTable)
    }
    suspend fun update(noteTable: NoteTable){
        noteDao.update(noteTable)
    }
    suspend fun delete(noteTable: NoteTable){
        noteDao.delete(noteTable)
    }
}
```

and the view model

```
class NotesViewModel(private val notesRepository: NotesRepository): ViewModel() {
    val getNotes:LiveData<List<NoteTable>> = notesRepository.allNotes
    fun insertNote(noteTable: NoteTable){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {notesRepository.insert(noteTable)  }
    }
    fun updateNote(noteTable: NoteTable){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            notesRepository.update(noteTable)
        }
    }
    fun deleteNote(noteTable: NoteTable){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) { notesRepository.delete(noteTable) }
    }

}
```

the layout for add the notes and update

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:background="@color/teal_200">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="ADD NOTES"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="ADD TITLE"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvText"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:inputType="text"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etDescription"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etTitle"
        android:hint="ADD DESCRIPTION"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:inputType="text"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnADD"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ADD"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etDescription"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/black"/>



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

please take a little time and help me to solve this